# Sorely missing graying out of unneeded "open" and unused declarations in F# and VS 2019

Tags: f#, visual-studio-2019

Why do I no longer see any grayed out **open** statements and declarations in the F# editor panes in Visual Studio 2019?

Yes, I did research whether there was another open issue anywhere, some news I missed, some setting that perhaps was changed, including coloring, but I can't see anything wrong.

If it's coloring that's bad, so that the graying out is actually there, but invisible to me, then I am not sure which color to reconfigure, but I don't think it's coloring. Not absolutely sure though, because I did notice coloring of something else changed after one of the updates - not sure which update. I also noticed that there seems to be less F# specific colors in the color list than what I can remember from the past, but I have no easy way to check that now. This is not at all the first time I've had this problem, and I think perhaps there was specific F# colors for grayed out items, that I imagine I used to fix this. Possibly false memory - for some reason I'm getting older all the time ...

I'm at VS 2019 v 16.0.3 at the moment.

I asked on F# Slack and created an issue here: https://github.com/microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/6706

So far no reaction on F# Slack and to that issue report.

Comment: I cannot replicate your issue on 16.0.3. When I add an unnecessarry `open System` it immediately gets grayed out. Do you have any extensions, like ReSharper that might be causing the issue?

Comment: No extensions I would suspect of doing anything like that, though VisualSVN is involved with the editor. I can try removing it when I can find some time.

Comment: I guess you tried repair or re-install?

Comment: No, not so far. It's on two machines, which I would guess makes it less likely to work. In addition, I can't squeeze that into my schedule at this time. That may have to wait until a complete reinstall of some machine, which statistically happens around twice a year per machine.